# How do I access the value of a textbox control on a subform where the subform itself is just a control on another subform of the main form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've just assumed responsibility for a database written ages ago in MS Access and I need to make some changes but unfortunately, even though I used to be a very experienced Access developer some time ago, I haven't really used it to an advanced level for about 15 years and I just can't work out how to do what I need.

Specifically, I have a main form called frmOrders.
On that form I have a subform called frmJobCard.
But frmJobCard is itself a form with a subform called frmSFJCOrders.
So, when someone clicks a particular button on frmOrders, I need to be able to read the value of a textbox on frmSFJCOrders and take action based on that value.

I've so far read through dozens of posts (both on StackOverflow and other techy sources) all of which touch upon different aspects of reading from controls on subforms and I've spent over a day trying to get this right but it never actually works so I'd be grateful if someone could tell me how I just read this value.

I think I need something along the lines of...

*If Forms.frmOrders.frmJobCard.Form.frmSFJCOrders.[Estimate QTY] = 0 Then*

...but I just can't make it work.

I would expect the code above to evaluate to 0 then take the actions below but it just always fails on the evaluation with

**Run-time error '2465':
Application-defined or object-defined error**

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could set it up so when that textbox gets filled it writes to a global variable, after that you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks but the issue with that approach is that a figure may be added and then later cleared so I'd need to spend time tracking down all the points at which I'd need to adjust that global variable based upon the actions taken.

In the end, this is probably what I'll do because I consider it to be a very sensible approach but right now I just need a quick fix and the easiest way is for me to just grab the value if I can. Once I've had time to look through the code I'll consider re-writing parts of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be close to this:

```
If Me!frmJobCard.Form!frmSFJCOrders.Form![Estimate QTY].Value = 0 Then
```

Note that frmJobCard and frmSFJCOrders must be names of the subform *controls* which may differ from the names of the forms.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution I saw first when I came back onto the question and even though I'm convinced it's EXACTLY the format I used at least once in my various attempts (although clearly I'm wrong because if it was, it would have worked without me needing to post on here) it worked perfectly for me - thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this [Access MVPs resource](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) which I bookmarked in my early Access programming days. Specifically you need `!` to delineate *within* objects and `.` to delineate *between* parent/child objects with `Form.` qualifier for every form object.

```vb
If Forms!frmOrders!frmJobCard.Form!frmSFJCOrders![Estimate QTY] = 0 Then
```

Alternatively, use a functional version:

```
If Forms("frmOrders").Controls("frmJobCard") _
                     .Controls("frmSFJCOrders") _
                     .Controls("[Estimate QTY]") = 0 Then
```